# Telegram bot excel python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-spreadsheet

Добрые люди помогите уже пару дней не могу понять что  делать!

Мне нужно Телеграм бот парсер по заданой строчки выводилась информация.
Например, у меня в `excel-листе` написано в первом столбе текст, а во втором инфа.

Мне нужно написать боту:

> ул. аношкина 85

а он мне выводит инфу, которая прописана на эту улицу.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ARLdxhbGGgsAPzcPZVL9Dh1TI2IKr1iJt-Pd5HJrmlI

Comment: Таблица недоступна по ссылке. К тому же не понятно, речь о `Google Sheets API` или об `MS Excel`?

Comment: Google Sheets API

Answer (score 0):

Для работы с Google Sheets API вам необходимо получить API ключ (в форме json).
Вот пример работы кода:

```
import httplib2
import apiclient.discovery
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

def auth(CREDENTIALS_FILE):
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        CREDENTIALS_FILE,
        ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])
    httpAuth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    return apiclient.discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http=httpAuth)

CREDENTIALS_FILE = ""#Название вашего json ключя
service = auth(CREDENTIALS_FILE)
```

После этого пишем функцию, которая возвращает инфу об адресе.

```
def get_info(address):

   def get_spreadsheet_values(list_name:str, range:str, type:str):
    values = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
        spreadsheetId = config.spreadsheet_id,
        range = "'" + list_name + "'!" + range,
        majorDimension = type
    ).execute()
    return(values['values'])


   def get_spreadsheet_data(range):
    # list_name = "Лист2"
    try:
        return get_spreadsheet_values(list_name, range, "ROWS")
    except:
        return []

   data = get_spreadsheet_data("A1:A999")  #2-у мерный массив, [[A1],[A2]......
   for i, el in enumerate(data):  
      if (el[0] == address):
      return get_spreadsheet_data("B"+i)[0][0]:
info = get_info(address)
```

(адреса в столбце A, Данные в столбце B)
Далее при помощи PyTelegramBotApi отправляем из пользователю

```
bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, 
                 , info)
```

[ccылка на официальный API от Google](https://developers.google.com/sheets)

[ccылка на пример простого проекта с Google Spreadsheet Api на gitHub](https://github.com/freQuensy23-coder/Student_Control) - именно из него я брал все функции получения информации по range итп. Данные с него так же отправляются пользователю через Telegram, но благодаря http API, возможно это вам будет предпочтительней.